# Given $\alpha, \beta \in \bar{F}$ are separable over $F$, prove that $\alpha + \beta$ is also separable over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

As the title says:

Given $\alpha, \beta \in \bar{F}$ are separable over $F$, prove that $\alpha + \beta$ is also separable over $F$.

I'd like a push in the right direction, not a complete answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separable extensions are a distinguished class. Furthermore, if $\alpha$ is separable over $F$, then it is separable over any algebraic extension of $F$. Is that enough of a hint?

Little further hint: $E/F$ is separable if and only if every $\alpha\in E$ is separable as an element over $F$.

Comment: Yep!  I had to stare at it for awhile but I think I've got it now.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Want to post your proof? I'll double-check it.

Comment: Can I check if I've understood correctly? $\alpha$ and $\beta$ separable $\implies $ $F(\alpha, \beta)$ is separable $\implies$ any $\gamma \in F(\alpha, \beta)$ is separable. So in particular $\alpha + \beta$ is separable.